# How Can I Implement Wide Angle Camera using CameraX and Camera2

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I want to add Wide Angle Camera's result in MLKit vision library. I have tried using Camera2 but unable to integrate it in Live Image Analysis and in CameraX can't find that much wide angle.
Can anyone suggest how can I implement it.